# converting double.NaN to the relevant culture in converter wpf

Tags: wpf, converters, cultureinfo, culture, nan

have a datatable which is being inserted with doubl.NaN when we dont have values.
What i want to do is whenever i see double.Nan i want to put "-" instead, therefore i have a converter with the following code:

```
        if (value.ToString() == double.NaN.ToString())
        {
            return "-";
        }
```

everything worked perfectly on "en-us" culture, but when we use different culture (like "zn-cn")
it doesnt work, due to the fact that "double.NaN.ToString()" results with a chinese word where value.ToString() is the normal "NaN".

i tried using double.parse() using the converters, nothing worked.

**Update -** ok the problem is that the converter gets the object as string and not as double this is the Xaml:

```
  <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type DataGridCell}">
                <Border Background="Transparent"  Padding="10 8" BorderBrush="Transparent"  BorderThickness="1">
                    <Border.Resources>
                        <Style TargetType="ToolTip">
                            <Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle" Value="true"/>
                            <Setter Property="HasDropShadow" Value="False"/>
                            <Setter Property="VerticalOffset" Value="-46"/>
                            <Setter Property="HorizontalOffset" Value="10"/>
                            <Setter Property="Template">
                                <Setter.Value>
                                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="ToolTip">
                                        <General:TextTooltip TitleStyle="{StaticResource NumericTableToolTipTitleStyle}"  Content="{TemplateBinding Content}" ContentStringFormat="G"  ContentStyle="{StaticResource NumericTableToolTipContentStyle}"/>
                                    </ControlTemplate>
                                </Setter.Value>
                            </Setter>
                        </Style>
                    </Border.Resources>
                    <TextBlock x:Name="tbCellText" Text="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, 
                               Path=Content.Text, Converter={StaticResource NumericTableCellContentConverter}, ConverterCulture={x:Static gl:CultureInfo.CurrentCulture}}"
                               ToolTip="{Binding ElementName=tbCellText, Path=Text}"
                               TextWrapping="Wrap"/>
                </Border>
            </ControlTemplate>
```

is there any way to preserve the type of the object?

i know i could just do a comparison with "NaN" but i would like more generic solution for that matter.

Comment: BTW, converters have converterculture as one of the parameters

Comment: yea i know but it doesnt help as long as the value is of string type...

Comment: @OriPrice see my answer, you're binding to the wrong property.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solution -** the problem is that i was binding the data table to a datagrid and only after that i am 
converting all values. Extracting values from data grid is always of type strig so there was my problem. i just need to use the converter while binding directly to the data table instead to datagrid cells.

Answer (score 2):

When you bind to a property of type `double` the converter gets a `value` parameter of type `double`. You could easily do this:

```
if (double.IsNaN((double)value))
{
    return "-";
}
```

Comment: thanks, but i tried it and it doesnt work. the value cannot be converted to double....

Comment: i thinks its because the value object is being converted to string ("NaN") somehow

Comment: Isn't the property you're binding to of type `double`? If it's a string that's always "NaN" when the value is `NaN`, your comparison could be as simple as `if (value as string == "NaN")`.

Comment: i am inserting it to a datatable (there its a double) then i am binding the datatable to a datagrid in the xaml with the relevant converter. i would expect that the value that arrive to the converter will stay the same (double) but apperantly it doesnt.... i dont want to relay on strings... is there any way to convert the string "NAN" to double?

Comment: With "relevant converter" you mean the converter we're talking about here? If the property that you bind to is of type `double`, then the converter gets a `value` parameter of type `double`. If that's not the case, you have to find out why. Perhaps you post the relevant XAML (with the binding).

Comment: i've confirmed that its actually a string so you are right and i think the problem is that its being converted to string in the control template.

Comment: maybe the problem is that i am converting the value AFTER binding the data table to a data grid and when extracting the value from data grid would always be a string?

Comment: Yes indeed, you should somehow bind directly to the data.

Answer (score 1):

`if (double.IsNaN(value)) ...` will do in any locale.

Documentation link: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.double.isnan.aspx

BTW, direct comparison to `double.NaN` (`if (value == double.NaN)`) won't work, as the comparison of `NaN` to `NaN` returns `false`! You could however detect `NaN` by such a trick: `if (value != value) ...` (this holds true only for `NaN`s). But an explicit test `double.IsNaN` is more readable.

Edit: as other answers suggest, inside the converter your `value` is perhaps not `double`, but `object`. So you'd need to include a check:

```
if (!(value is double))
    return ""; // or signal an error, or whatever
double d = (double)value;
if (double.IsNaN(d))
    return "-";
...
```

Comment: thanks, but i tried it and it doesnt work. the value cannot be converted to double....

Comment: @Ori: Well, could you please look in the debugger, what is the actual type of `value`?

Comment: yes its a string instead of double. updated the post (added the relevant Xaml)

Comment: @Ori: Hmmm. Where does this string come from? Which code have converted `double.NaN` to the localized string?

Answer (score 1):

One little addition to Vlad:

if (value is double && double.IsNaN((double)value))

Comment: thanks, but i tried it and it doesnt work. the value cannot be converted to double....

Comment: what type of value do you have in a value parameter?

Comment: string. i dont know where it comes from.

Comment: That means you're binding to a string value. Why don't you consider binding to an original double value? Try to remove "Path=Content.Text," part from your binding. I suppose, DataContext of the DataGridCell should be the original value.

Comment: actually i stll have a problem. the datacontext of the DataGridCell is of a DataRow type. not a specific cell. so i get the whole row in the converter.

Answer (score 0):

Don't bind to the content.text property in your datagridcell. That's why the value is coming in as a string.

Try storing the data value in the Tag property of the TextBlock and bind to that, then in property updated code, set the value of the text.